# How Create shopping cart rule 10% off on $100 Grand Total MAgento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4.2

I have to create shopping cart rule like, 10% off on minimum $100 spent.

$100 will be a grand Total (Total after discount,Including tax)

Answer (score 0):

Create Rule :
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Subtotal (Incl. Tax)  equals or greater than  100

Comment: Hi @Oscprofessionals I want Shopping cart price rule applied at Grand total (or subtotal after discount)